# Interface of container in c++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, interface, iterator

I am writing my own containers for working with sets. I implement an ordered set based on an AVL tree. I want all set containers to support operations with sets, so I inherited the AVLTree implementation from the ISet interface of the set.

```cpp
template<class T>
class Blaze::ISet {
 public:
    virtual size_t size() const = 0;
    virtual bool empty() const = 0;

    virtual void erase(const T& val) = 0;
    virtual void insert(const T& val) = 0;
    virtual bool contains(const T& val) const = 0;

    virtual bool is_disjoint(const ISet &other) const noexcept = 0;

    virtual bool is_equal(const ISet &other) const noexcept = 0;
    virtual bool operator==(const ISet &other) const noexcept = 0;

    virtual bool is_subset(const ISet &other) const noexcept = 0;
    virtual bool operator<=(const ISet &other) const noexcept = 0;

    virtual bool is_superset(const ISet &other) const noexcept = 0;
    virtual bool operator>=(const ISet &other) const noexcept = 0;

    virtual std::unique_ptr<ISet> Union(const ISet &other) const = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<ISet> operator|(const ISet &other) const = 0;

    virtual std::unique_ptr<ISet> intersection(const ISet &other) const = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<ISet> operator&(const ISet &other) const = 0;

    virtual std::unique_ptr<ISet> difference(const ISet &other) const = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<ISet> operator-(const ISet &other) const = 0;

    virtual ~ISet() = 0;
};
```

But there was a problem. For example, for the Union operation, I need to go through all the elements of another set - respectively, the begin and end methods should be available in the interface.

```cpp
template<class T, class Less>
requires std::copyable<T> && std::semiregular<Less> && Blaze::comparable_with<T, Less>
std::unique_ptr<Blaze::ISet<T, const_iterator>> Blaze::AVLTree<T, Less>::Union(const Blaze::ISet<T, const_iterator> &other) const {
    auto result = std::make_unique<AVLTree<T, Less>>(*this);
    for (const T& elem : other) {
        result->insert(elem);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But I can't add these methods to the interface, because the interface can't know which Iterator class is returned in the inheritor in the begin() method, and I can't make this method a template, because it's a pure virtual function, how do I get out of this situation?

In general, is it a good idea to make an interface for a container?

Comment: Is this for a school or similar assignment or exercise? Because otherwise, what's wrong with either [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is not-copyable, how you expect it be returned? Also, this is one of reasons why  standard containers are templates, not polymorphic classes. In limited way you can use CRTP.

Comment: As for the problem of iterators and inheritance, perhaps use [the curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)? Then the base class can use the child-class iterator type for its (virtual) `begin` and `end` functions. Or think a bit more about your design, so that you don't need different iterators for the child-classes? Perhaps use container *adaptors* (like `std::stack` and `std::queue`) instead?

Comment: Another idea could be not to use an interface, but a concept instead.